# Only 'master' inside the system databases in Azure Managed instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

During our POC we saw the system databases(model,msdb and tempdb) lying outside the system databases group.

Any specific reason behind it?[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a Managed Instance? Some flavors of Azure SQL don't include the typical system databases. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100806/azure-sql-server-system-databases. (But that would mean someone created model, msdb, and tempdb as user databases, which would be very strange.)

Comment: Just had to use latest SSMS..we were using previous versions with azure db and expected it would be fine..then this happened and we are fine now. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just because of the SSMS version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695590/create-database-using-ssms-gui-fails-for-azure-sql-managed-instance

Used 17.9.1 and can see things lined up properly. Probably the previous version was treating as Azure database.